# How can I constrain a topology in BEAST using a newick tree that has a different number of taxa?

Tags: constraints, analysis, phylogeny

I have a newick tree with excellent support that was constructed using 11 mitochondrial CDS, but it has only 14 species from 2 localities represented. Therefore I would like to incorporate my COI dataset which has many species from many localities represented. The COI dataset alone always has fairly poor support, so I want to use the 11 CDS tree to constrain the topology of the COI tree to build a better tree with more taxa represented. I am using BEAST2 v2.7.5, and am using a MultiMonophyletic Constraint prior to enter my constraint tree and am using the same newick tree as the starting topology, but I am getting an error saying the taxa in the COI dataset are not found in the 11CDS dataset, which of course they wont because they are not in that tree:
WARNING: The number of taxa (71) does not match the number of leafs in the tree (14)
I've verified that the 14 tips of the CDS tree match names found in the COI dataset.

Is there a way to relax the analysis so that the topology of the taxa in both files remain constant while the relationships of additional taxa in the COI dataset can move around?
Thanks in advance.

I updated my BEAST software to the lastest to make sure that wasn't an issue. I've tried manually modifying the xml files, but that created more problems. I've followed instructions on all the BEAST documentary for this issue, but there's no resources for how to do this with different numbers of taxa in each dataset.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I can see three alternative solutions, out of which only the first one uses BEAST:

1. Use topology priors for all 13 nodes in your 14-leaf CDS tree. Each prior will enforce monophyly for a set of taxa descending from the specific node. A suitable starting tree will need to be provided.
2. Include COI sequences as a partition in an alignment containing the 11 CDS sequences, and infer the phylogeny from the supermatrix. The alignment will have a lot of missing data (I assume 10 loci for 57 taxa), but maximum likelihood and Bayesian inference methods [are robust](https://doi.org/10.25225/fozo.v61.i3.a10.2012) for analysing such data.
3. Use [Evolutionary Placement Algorithm](https://cme.h-its.org/exelixis/web/software/epa/index.html) to add your 57 taxa to the 14 taxa tree. This solution will likely perform worst in the case when the number of taxa to be added is much larger than the number of taxa in the backbone phylogeny.